# Show second form instead of first form when winforms loaded in C#

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I have two windows forms. I want to show the second form when my first form is  loaded.But the problem is that after the first form is loaded, it shows both forms without hiding my first form. Please check my code below.  Thank you for any solutions!

```
 form2 frm2= new form2();
 private void form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
     form1 frm1 = new form1();
     frm1 = this;
     frm1.Hide();
     frm2.Show();  
    }
```

Comment: You want to load a form, just to hide it immediately and show another form? Why? Just do `Application.Run(new LoginForm());` followed by `Application.Run(new MainForm());` in your `Main` method.

Comment: Additionally the Load Event occurs before showing the Form. Trying to hide something before it is shown is useless. You surely want a modal login so atleast call ShowModal instead of Show.

Comment: Simply use ShowDialog() instead.  And pay attention to its return value.  And don't put your own insecure login procedure on top of the secure one that Windows provides, you are not talking to a stranger on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

We have following problems here :

1. Form Load loads the form *before* time when it's painted. So if we hide form from here it still draws it in the Paint event.
2. If we use Paint event to hide the main form and show our second form then we'll have problems to show our main form when we'll need it becuase this invokes paint event and it'll hide it again.

So there is three possible solutions:

1. Use form load but hide it from a separate thread.
2. We can create bool variable like `isInitialized` set to `false` and change it to `true` after 1st run in Paint event
3. We can leave main form visible and use ShowDialog() to show your second form

**1 - - >**

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        // We start a new task to handle our UI operations
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            this.Hide();
            this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                Form frm = new Form();
                frm.Show();
                frm.FormClosing += (s, o) => this.Show();
            }), null);                
        });
    }
```

**2 - - >**

```
bool isInitialized = false;

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   if(isInitialized) return;
   Form frm = new Form();
   frm.Show();
   frm.FormClosing += (s, o) => this.Show();
   this.Hide();
   isInitialized = true;
}
```

Comment: For the first solution method i got an error : "Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on." in this.Hide();
And the second solution it work well. 
But I just curios what is the difference between using Load event and Paint event?

Answer (score 0):

From your mentioned code, I understand that you are trying to close a login form and trying to open up a main form. You can try this piece of code for the same. This code will go into your Program.cs

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    Form1 form_login= new Form1();

    Application.Run(form_login);

    if (form_login.Authentication_success)
    {
        Application.Run(new Form2());
    }
}
```

In your form1 declare a public variable

```
public bool Authentication_success= true;
```

Next in your Form1 Load event, add the following code

```
Authentication_success= true;
this.Close();
```

Hope this solution is helpful. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    Form2 frm = new Form2();
                    frm.Show();
                    frm.FormClosing += (s, o) => this.Show();
                }));
                return;
            }

        });
    }
```

but I think following suggestions in comments under your question is better :)

Comment: The solution (comments) below my question isn't what I want. I want my second form show when my condition is true. So if i'm directly change in program.cs then i cannot use any condition to check it the second form should show or shouldn't show.
Anyway ur solution also work well too. Thx :)