# Duplicate parent forms as a result of calling a function from a child form

Tags: c#, forms, parent-child

In my application I have a parent form and a popup form. In the popup form when i click on button1, the application is supposed to call a function and as a result of the function, a label has to change its text. Although the popup button works, I have two parent forms; one with the label in its default state and one with the label changed as a result of clicking on the button in popup. Is there a way for me to hide the initial parent form? Here is the code I'm using in the popup form:

```
 public Form1 f1 = new Form1();
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        f1.referansyaz = true;
        f1.Show();

    }
```

So when I change the variable "referansyaz" to true, I call a function in form 1 and as a result of this function a label in form 1 (or the parent form) changes. And f1.show(), opens up the updated form 1.

Comment: Were does this second parent Form came from (with initial value of a label) ? Could you please more specific of what do you want...  Please check my answer to other question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31582159/show-second-form-instead-of-first-form-when-winforms-loaded-in-c-sharp/31582557#31582557

Comment: 'public Form1 f1 = new Form1();' this line is creating new instance of parent form. As @GrantWinney said you need to pass reference to your initial parent form.

Comment: And how do I do that? Can you specify your answer a little more in the answers section.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a second instance of `Form1` is *not* what you want to do.

Modify your popup form to accept a reference to the original form:

```
public class PopupForm : Form
{
    private Form1 f1;

    public PopupForm(Form1 f1)
    {
        this.f1 = f1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f1.referansyaz = true;

        Close();
    }

    // rest of form
    ...
}
```

Pass the reference when you instantiate the popup form:

```
var popupForm = new PopupForm(this);

popupForm.ShowDialog();
```

Typically though, I'd create a public property on the child form...

```
public class PopupForm : Form
{
    public bool Referansyaz { get; private set; }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Referansyaz = true;

        Close();
    }

    // rest of form
    ...
}
```

... to be consumed by the parent, after the child (popup) form is closed:

```
var popupForm = new PopupForm();

popupForm.ShowDialog();

referansyaz = popupForm.Referansyaz;
```

That way, changing the name of a field in the parent form doesn't break the child form too.

Comment: where do i add the last 2 lines of code? (ie. var popupForm = new PopupForm(this); popupForm.ShowDialog();)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code like this and pass a method that changes your label on parent form with a delegate to your second form. I'd strongly recommend *not* to pass an instance of your parent form to child form because it breaks *open-closed principle*...

So in your main form type:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form 
{
   public Action<bool> a;  `     
   public Form1()
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      a = new Action<bool>(newValue => this.referansyaz.Text = newValue.ToString());
   }

  // some code where you create your Form2

   Form2 newForm = new Form2(a);
}
```

Then in your second form :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
   Action<bool> a; 

   public Form2(Action<bool> a)
   {
      this.a = a;
   }

   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {      
      a(true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried hiding it using:

```
this.Hide();
```

Here's what worked for me:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form1 f1 = new Form1();
        f1.referansyaz = true;
        f1.Show();
    }
```

Comment: no it doesn't work, since this.Hide() hides the popup window. It doesn't hide the initial parent form.

Comment: Do you call it before f1.Show() ?

Comment: I want to hide the parent form (aka form1), this.Hide() hides the popup form (aka form2).